# teechart on windows store app shows incorrect candle colours

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, teechart

I am using the teechart control within a windows store app. There seems to be a problem displaying a candle stick series. The candles aren't coloured correctly according to a rising or descending close value. It seems to take the direction of the first value in the series and apply this to the the rest of the values.

I have set up 2 new projects to prove this. A blank wpf project and a blank store app. I have used the same xaml and c# code in each. The wpf app displays the data correctly yet the store app does not. Can anyone confirm that this is a bug? and can anyone on the teechart team say when this is going to be addressed?

My data series looks like this on both apps. In WPF i have 5 rising candles followed by 3 falling. Using the store.dll, all 8 are rising.

```
CandleSticks.Add(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-10), 2, 10, 2, 4);
CandleSticks.Add(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-9), 4, 5, 3, 5);
CandleSticks.Add(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-8), 5, 7, 5, 6);
CandleSticks.Add(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-7), 6, 14, 3, 8);
CandleSticks.Add(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-6), 8, 10, 6, 9);
CandleSticks.Add(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5), 9, 10, 2, 6);
CandleSticks.Add(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4), 6, 10, 4, 5);
CandleSticks.Add(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3), 5, 10, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Maybe http://www.teechart.net/support/index.php is a better place to post this question? The teechart team is presumably actively monitoring that one...

Comment: Which version of TeeChart.Store.dll are you using? Using the latest publicly available version, both TeeChart.Store.dll and TeeChart.WPF.dll give identical results for the same Candle sample data. I can't paste in the code I used, as there is not enough space here.

Comment: I'm unable to use the teechart support forum as i only have a trial licence. I'm building a native charting component for an app we all ready have as a proof on concept before i can persuade my company to purchase it.

Comment: I have added my data series to the original post

Comment: oh and i've tried versions 4.1.2015.03115 & 4.1.2015.05146 which i believe are the newest versions.

Comment: Try setting "Utils.UseCaches = false;" as the first line of code. This is a small defect which has been fixed for the latest version, due out within the next month.

Comment: yes, thank you, that works :)